# printf() producing garbage

Tags: c, printf

```
char username[50];

printf("[Enter Command]: \n");
scanf("%s", username);

if (strcmp("exit", username) == 0) {
    exit(0);
}

if (strcmp("jobs", username) == 0) {
    printf("[SERVER] No currently running jobs\n");
}

char dtm[50];
char first_word[50];
char second_word[50];


strcpy(dtm, username);
sscanf(dtm, "%s %s", first_word, second_word);

printf("%s %s\n", first_word, second_word);
```

I want to extract the first and second word of my inputted string. I don't understand why my printf() statement is producing garbage outputs

Comment: What are the return values of all called functions?

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: if `dtm` contains only one word, then `second_word` is garbage, yes. check return value of `scanf`. It must be 2.

Comment: Load your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example into a debugger and look at all the variables.

Comment: You do know that the `"%s"` format stops on *space*? Perhaps you want [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a whole line?

Comment: yeah, so `dtm` _always_ contains one word, the second one is garabge

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP cannot spell "garbage"

Comment: Checking the return value from `sscanf` (should be `2`) would have told you this. Always check user input, because ***that*** is the usual source of garbage, either accidentally, by misunderstanding, or mischief.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `scanf("%s", username);` with `gets(username);`(line 3).
Thats where your problem is. Scanf is only taking the first word.

Comment: Do not suggest using the deprecated function `gets`, you should suggest using `fgets`

Answer (score 0):

Please always keep in my that `printf` never produce any garbage. It is we creates these issues by our self. While playing with string always be careful and to instruct `printf` end of a string we must put a end of string character at the end of a string and that is call null character `\0` or 0. Some of the C function does not insert a `\0` character at the end of the string and hence it is our duty to take care of it. Better always initialize a string with 0 in all the location like below, this is one of the good practice to avoid side effect like this.

```
char dtm[50];
char first_word[50];
char second_word[50];

memset(dtm, 0, 50);//or memset(dtm, 0, sizeof(dtm));
memset(first_word, 0, 50);//or memset(first_word, 0, sizeof(first_word));
memset(second_word, 0, 50);// or memset(second_word, 0, sizeof(second_word));
```

Below practice is also safe.

```
char dtm[50] = "";
char first_word[50] = "";
char second_word[50] = "";
```

Comment: `memset` works but is OTT. `char dtm[50] = "";` reads better.

Comment: Yes true. Thanks for your comments. I have modified my answer based on your advice.